# Comparing Blob fields

Tags: blob, delphi-2009

My example is that I am using a fingerprint scanner, the fingerprint data is stored in a blob field, so I want to make sure that the same fingerprint does not get inserted, so whats the best way to compare these fields.

Answer (score 1):

This does not seem to be about delphi or blob fields at all, since "the same fingerprint" will rarely (if ever) happen. Even the same person will produce slightly different images every time (s)he puts a finger on the scanner. Therefore the real problem is not checking for equality but checking for close matches which is a nontrivial problem in and of itself. You should consult specialized literature.

Comment: I think maybe we are not on the same page, let me give you a scenario, can we say I register you as an employee using your fingerprint, and another person comes and wants to get registered, what can I do to make sure that this fingerprint I am registering is not yours?

Comment: Again: You're looking for an algorithm to find close-enough matches between to two fingerprints (mine in the database and the one you're trying to enter). If these fingerprints are just images (which I suppose they are) this is a nontrivial question about image processing. My suggestion is to find about image-comparison algorithms, lookup how existing software does this etc.